# Smoothing Line in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geemap

How can I get a smoother line?

```
var image = ee.Image('users/cananhamzaolu/KIYI500')
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon = ([
    [31.577169138841125, 41.30667497201365],
    [33.33498163884112, 41.30667497201365],
    [33.33498163884112, 41.91451886804031],
    [31.577169138841125, 41.91451886804031],
    [31.577169138841125, 41.30667497201365]
])
var clip = image.clip(roi)
Map.addLayer(clip, {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 1
}, 'image', false)
var canny = ee.Algorithms.CannyEdgeDetector({
    image: clip,
    threshold: 0,
    sigma: 1
});
Map.addLayer(canny, {
    'min': 0,
    'max': 1
}, 'canny')
```

Comment: Pease explain your problem and steps you took to try and solve it, and include your actual code rather than a link.

Comment: thank you so much,I edited

Comment: I guess you want to do "vector-simplification-like" simplification. You can make a line (vector) from raster, simplify the line, convert to raster. But I don't know how to do in GEE.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz yes, I converted it to vector but I run across scale problem. My interest of region is huge and When I determined scale as 30, I got a problem. When I determined the scale as 1000 the lines seems weird

Answer (score 0):

As @kadir suggested you can use a reduceToVector similar to this:

```
var toVec = canny.select('b1').int().reduceToVectors({
  geometry: roi,
  crs: image.projection(),
  scale: 100,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
  eightConnected: false,
  labelProperty: 'zone',

  
})
```

Be aware that this creates a vector around your pixels, so it will not be a single line representing the pixels. You'll have to smooth that with the .simplify() functionallity.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a15a4a9d9eefb7741636d3eebbf12fc

Comment: yes,I got like image,I will try to apply simplify function

Comment: glad it worked, if you believe this answered your question it might be helpful to others as well if you accept it.

Comment: can i edit my line without converting it to vector? Because when I convert the line to vector the line does not represent the shore boundary correctly

Comment: Yes you can, but not sure what you want? Perhaps ask a separate question for that because getting your line to 'represent' the shore boundary is a whole other story

Comment: yeah you are right :)